# Allow only Angular application to access Node application (Same EC2 instance)and block Node for everybody else

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, security-groups

I have hosted both my angular(port no 4200) and node application(port no 3000) on the same EC2 instance.
Both are currently accessible to anyone.
I want to limit access to the Node application so that only Angular is able to connect with it and blocked for everyone else.

What I have already done:-

1. EC2 security group inbound rule for port 3000 set to its own **public** IP
   xx.xx.xx.xx/32
2. EC2 security group inbound rule for port 3000 set to its own **private** IP
   172.xx.xx.xx/32

In both cases, I am getting timed out error from my node application.

OPTIONS http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Answer (score 0):

If they are on the *same instance* you may want to refer to the NodeJS app *from Angular* as **`http://127.0.0.1:3000`** - that way the traffic stays completely inside the machine and won't traverse the AWS infrastructure at all.

See **[Localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)** for more info.